# Rewrite array based on another array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

So this is a weird one. I have two arrays one array that is a list of events. If there is no events it just has a zero. Another array that counts the number of items that equal 0. Basically what I can't figure out is how to adjust the first array based on the second array.

What I would like to do create an array that removes some of the empty after the first empty and rewrite the value to say something different...kinda like this. I would like to rewrite so it grabs the gives a generic title and event time and start based on the first point of the 0 and the last zero value.

Basically the reason I have to do this is we are trying to use a clients api for schedule making. Problem is the api they are using doesn't accommodate for open times slots which they want to show. So what I"m trying to do is loop through the number of hours they are open, add events based on event time, then create blank events in between events. Problem is I am having trouble creating the blank events.

Thanks! I'm not the best php developer I actually had a coworker help get me this far I just can't figure out how/what functions to use to achieve this.

Ideal Array

```
IdealArray
(
[0600] => Array
   (
        [e_name] => No events
        [e_start] => 6000
        [e_end] => 1000
    )
[1000] => Array
    (
        [e_name] =>  Event One
        [e_start] => 1000
        [e_end] => 1100
    )
[1100] => Array
   (
        [e_name] => No events
        [e_start] => 1000
        [e_end] => 1630
    )
[1630] => Array
    (
        [e_name] => Event Number 2
        [e_start] => 1630
        [e_end] => 0930
    )
[0930] => Array
   (
        [e_name] => No events
        [e_start] => 0930
        [e_end] => 1100
    )
)
```

Current Arrays

```
First Array
(
[0600] => 0
[0630] => 0
[0700] => 0
[0730] => 0
[0800] => 0
[0830] => 0
[0900] => 0
[0930] => 0
[1000] => Array
    (
        [e_name] =>  Event One
        [e_start] => 1000
        [e_end] => 1100
    )

[1100] => 0
[1130] => 0
[1200] => 0
[1230] => 0
[1300] => 0
[1330] => 0
[1400] => 0
[1430] => 0
[1500] => 0
[1530] => 0
[1600] => 0
[1630] => Array
    (
        [e_name] => Event Number 2
        [e_start] => 1630
        [e_end] => 1930
    )

[1930] => 0
[2000] => 0
[2030] => 0
[2100] => 0
[2130] => 0
[2200] => 0
[2230] => 0
) 

Second Array
 (
[0] => 8
[1] => 11
[2] => 7
)
```

Comment: It's totally unclear what's the logic behind your rewriting.

Comment: Thanks I'll edit it.

Comment: Is the second array provided? Or do you need to produce that from the first array? I'm thinking it's not necessary.

Comment: I created the second array. It just counts how many are equal to zero in-between each. It should be listed at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the source array provided in the question (named `$First_Array` below), and assuming it's always in chronological order:

```
$start_time = '';               // keep track of "no event" starts
$summary = array();             // array for event summary

foreach ( $First_Array as $time => $event ) {

    if ( '' === $start_time ) { // empty string means new start
        $start_time = $time;
        $summary[$start_time] = array(
          'e_name' => 'No events', 'e_start' => $start_time, 'e_end' => ''
        );
    }

    if ( is_array($event) ) {                   // array means there's an event
        $summary[$start_time]['e_end'] = $time; // end last 'no events'
        $summary[$time] = $event;               // add event to summary
        $start_time = '';                       // reset start
    }
}
$summary[$start_time]['e_end'] = $time;         // get last end time
print_r($summary);
```

If order is not guaranteed, then simply start with a key sort: `ksort($First_Array)`

[PHP Sandbox example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/261b848150111ba953c3ec3defad5d55f20f70d6)

Comment: That is so much easeir than my thought process.